# The ideal for image of Segre embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How to show the ideal $(X_{ij}X_{kl}-X_{il}X_{kj})_{0\le i,k\le m, 0\le j,l\le n}\subset k[X_{ij}]_{0\le i\le m, 0\le j\le n}$ is radical? I can show the zero locus defined by the ideal is the image of $\mathbf{P}_k^{m-1}\times\mathbf{P}^{n-1}_k\to\mathbf{P}_k^{mn-1}$, but I think this may not imply the ideal is radical. (The same question for the quadratic defining relations for Plücker embedding, why do they generate a radical ideal?)

Comment: In fact these ideals are even prime. For the general case see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54101/are-the-determinantal-ideals-prime-ideals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k[X_{ij}]_{0\le i\le m, 0\le j\le n}/(X_{ij}X_{kl}-X_{il}X_{kj})_{0\le i,k\le m, 0\le j,l\le n}$ is isomorphic to the Segre product of two polynomial rings in $m+1$, respectively $n+1$ indeterminates over $k$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139531/is-this-quotient-ring-mathbbcz-ij-ker-phi-integrally-closed). This is at its turn a subring of their tensor product, and therefore an integral domain.